# Writing only a particular tag's line number with conditions from xml file

Tags: python-3.x

I have a xml file, in that file I have a tag named as SN and it occurs in multiple places.How do I write these line numbers as a list to another file.

Comment: What is your tag named as ?

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: Tag is <SN> which I missed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to get a line number from an ElementTree Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6949395/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-line-number-from-an-elementtree-element)

Comment: Those methods did not work, so it is not a duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you can use sourceline!Have a look at the example I have given below. Assuming you have a SN tag in xml file at multiple places.

```
    from lxml import etree
    context = etree.terparse(your_file_path)
    line_number=[]
    for action,elem in context:
        if elem.tag=="SN" :
            print(elem.text)
            a=elem.sourceline
            print(a)
            line_number.append(a)
```

So here you have a empty list as line_number and when you go through the for loop fetching SN you can get its line number by sourceline and then append it to the list.

Comment: Yes I am able to get the SN line numbers this way, thanks.

Comment: Now you can use file write to write these to a file.Hope you know those steps.