# Unable to debug into xml.etree.ElementTree

Tags: python, python-3.x, elementtree, pdb

I am seeing a very weird behavior in which I can't step into or put breakpoint in some of the ElementTree classes. I started with the below code:

```py
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

print(f"{ET.__file__}")
et = ET.parse("/tmp/pom.xml")
print(et)
```

I got the below output:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/xml/etree/ElementTree.py
<xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree object at 0x10fef9a30>
```

So, I opened the `ElementTree.py` file and put a breakpoint into `class XMLParser.__init__` ([here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/eff4aa5409a0dfe6ccd5ef4662578c77ee2954f1/Lib/xml/etree/ElementTree.py#L1521)), but the breakpoint didn't get hit.

```py
class XMLParser:
    ...
    def __init__(self, *, target=None, encoding=None):
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        try:
            from xml.parsers import expat
        except ImportError:
```

Then I added a breakpoint into the `ElementTree.parse` ([here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/eff4aa5409a0dfe6ccd5ef4662578c77ee2954f1/Lib/xml/etree/ElementTree.py#L574)):

```py
    def parse(self, source, parser=None):
        ...
        close_source = False
        if not hasattr(source, "read"):
            source = open(source, "rb")
            close_source = True
        try:
            if parser is None:
                # If no parser was specified, create a default XMLParser
                import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
                parser = XMLParser()
                if hasattr(parser, '_parse_whole'):
```

I did get pdb prompt, but when I tried to step into `XMLParser`, it went straight to the next line. I even ensured that it is referring to the same local class (not some native implementation):

```
(Pdb) import inspect
(Pdb) inspect.getmodule(XMLParser)
<module 'xml.etree.ElementTree' from '/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/xml/etree/ElementTree.py'>
```

The reason I am doing this is to figure out why overridden `_start` and `_end` methods are not getting invoked for my custom class that extends `XMLParser`. I am instantiating the parser something like this (derived from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36430270/95750), with `_start_list` changed to `_start`):

```py
class LineNumberingParser(ET.XMLParser):
    def _start(self, *args, **kwargs):
        element = super()._start(*args, **kwargs)
        element._start_line_number = self.parser.CurrentLineNumber
        print(f"----- {element.tag} {element._start_line_number}")
        return element

    def _end(self, *args, **kwargs):
        element = super()._end(*args, **kwargs)
        element._end_line_number = self.parser.CurrentLineNumber
        print(f"----- {element.tag} {element._end_line_number}")
        return element


parser = LineNumberingParser(target=ET.TreeBuilder(insert_comments=True))
et = ET.parse("/tmp/pom.xml", parser)
```

I even tried adding a constructor to `LineNumberingParser` and stepping into the `super` constructor, but I got the same behavior as before, though I can see that the `self` instance gets initialized properly (e.g., `self.target` is `None` before `super.__init__` call but initialized after).

**What am I missing here?**

**Update 1**: I put some `print` statements in very obvious places in `XMLParser` (like `__init__` and `_start`) and got no output, so it seems like it is using a different implementation though `inspect.getmodule` says otherwise.

**Update 2**: I just noticed the [below](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/eff4aa5409a0dfe6ccd5ef4662578c77ee2954f1/Lib/xml/etree/ElementTree.py#L2072) at the end of the module:

```py
# Import the C accelerators
try:
    # Element is going to be shadowed by the C implementation. We need to keep
    # the Python version of it accessible for some "creative" by external code
    # (see tests)
    _Element_Py = Element

    # Element, SubElement, ParseError, TreeBuilder, XMLParser, _set_factories
    from _elementtree import *
    from _elementtree import _set_factories
except ImportError:
    pass
else:
    _set_factories(Comment, ProcessingInstruction)
```

I guess it indeed was a C native implementation and that is why pdb wasn't stepping in (the answer to my original question). Now I am back to square one to find a solution for line numbers.

**Update 3**: I found the [code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/eff4aa5409a0dfe6ccd5ef4662578c77ee2954f1/Lib/test/test_xml_etree.py#L4156) used in the test module to skip native module and `_start` and `_end` do get called with the python implementations, but there are some significant differences in the write code path.