# How to locate a node in an xml file by xml.etree module?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am using module `xml.etree` in `Python3` to parse an `xml` file.

Here is a code sample:

```py
# test.py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
node = root[0]
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0.0"?>
<root>
    <node>test</node>
</root>
```

I want to get the position of `node` in `test.xml`, i.e., `line 2, column 5` (or at least `line2`).

How can I implement this function?

I skimmed the methods of `ElementTree` class, but found no method for it.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/6949395/407651

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution for your Question :

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
//here get the content of node
for child in root.iter('node'):
    print(str(child.text))

file_info = open('test.xml', 'r')
//here to find index
node_line_indexes = []


for i, line in enumerate(file_info.readlines()): 
    if 'node' in line:
        #extract line index for lines that contain //
        node_line_indexes.append(i )
print (node_line_indexes)
```

test.xml contains your xml data

and here is a good examples and explain for xml.etree with python

https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Answer (score 0):

xML doesn’t have a line number. If you know enumerate() you can easily do something similar, but with some restriction, e.g. comments:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from io import StringIO


xml ="""<?xml version="1.0.0"?>
<root>
    <node>test</node>
    <!-- comment -->
    <node>test</node>
</root>"""

f= StringIO(xml)

tree = ET.parse(f)
root = tree.getroot()

# If xml declaration is ln_no 0, but keep in mind comment lines are not counted.
for ln_no, elem in enumerate(root.iter(), start=1):
    print(ln_no, elem.tag)
```

Output:

```
1 root
2 node
3 node
```